# How to Merge and Format Lists

Tags: python

I have two nested lists:

```
l1 = [['a', 'b'], ['d', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['b', 'a'], ['d', 'a']]
l2 = [['a', 'alpha'], ['b', 'beta'], ['c', 'gamma'], ['d', 'delta']]
```

(`l1` is completely unsorted but `l2` is in alphabetical order, in case that is relevant.)

Basically I want to end up with another list like this:

```
l3 = [['alpha', ['beta', 'gamma']], ['beta', ['alpha', 'gamma'], ['gamma', ['delta']], ['delta', ['alpha']]
```

So: merge the lists inside `l1` which share a common first element then replace all the values in `l1` with their corresponding values in `l2` and finally format them in the manner of `l3` (with the nested lists e.g. `['beta', 'gamma']` in alphabetical order).

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391201/python-merge-lists-by-common-element/) is similar to what I want to do but I was unable to modify the answers given to fit my problem.)

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like what you want in your results should be a dictionary not a list of lists? Are you sure you want to use a list there?

Comment: Did you mean to put no commas between `['d', 'b'] ['b', 'c']` and `['b', 'a'] ['d', 'a']` in `l1`?

Comment: @IanAuld: Yes, sorry, I've been away from Python for a long time and completely forgot about dictionaries!

Comment: @Jarad: No that was a mistake, I'll edit them in. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dictionaries for (a) mapping the letters to words, and (b) for merging the lists. Particularly, have a look at [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make it a bit easier.

```
>>> l1 = [['a', 'b'], ['d', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['b', 'a'], ['d', 'a']]
>>> l2 = [['a', 'alpha'], ['b', 'beta'], ['c', 'gamma'], ['d', 'delta']]
>>> d2 = dict(l2)
>>> d3 = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for x, y in l1:
...     d3[d2[x]].append(d2[y])
...
>>> d3
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'alpha': ['beta', 'gamma'], 
                            'beta': ['gamma', 'alpha'], 
                            'gamma': ['delta'], 
                            'delta': ['beta', 'alpha']})
```

If you prefer the result as a list of sorted lists, just get the `items` from the dict.

```
>>> sorted([k, sorted(v)] for k, v in d3.items())
[['alpha', ['beta', 'gamma']],
 ['beta', ['alpha', 'gamma']],
 ['delta', ['alpha', 'beta']],
 ['gamma', ['delta']]]
```

Comment: I was typing out a solution and then realized it was identical to this except the variable names.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I'll certainly be looking into defaultdict further.