# Making dynamic lists to print out variables

Tags: python

How can I make a dynamic list and then print it out, this example is just an idea of what I want to do, the lists could be in the hundreds.

But I want anything that has cat to print "cat" with any value associated with it listed below it,

data = [["cat","one"], ["dog", "one"], ["cat", "ten"], ["frog", "one"], ["dog", "ten", "green"]]

```
#Would like this to print out like:

cat
one
ten

dog
one
ten
green

frog
one
```

Comment: sorry, your example explains pretty much nothing of what you want to do. what have you tried?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391201/python-merge-lists-by-common-element

Answer (score 6):

You can use a defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

groups = defaultdict(list)
for animal, value in data:
    groups[animal].append(value)

for animal, values in groups.items():
    print(animal)
    for value in values:
        print(value)
```

Comment: Actually I'm sorry that doesn't work I gave a bad example, how would I do that with strings at with more than just one after the animal name?

Comment: @Aladine,  slice `for ele in data: groups[ele[0]] = groups[1:]` or using python3 `for key, *vals in data: groups[key] = vals`, if you want a single string using `" ".join(vals)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setdefault`.

```
result = {}
for animal, value in data:
    result.setdefault(animal, []).append(value)
print(result)
```